Move /boot/efi and /boot to a separate disk
I would like to encrypt my root partition with the help of luks. For that I am thinking to move my boot partition to a smaller disk.
My current layout of the disk is:
$ lsblk -f
/dev/sdc
|-/dev/sdc1
|-/dev/sdc2 vfat FAT32 /boot/efi
|_/dev/sdc3 ext4 1.0   /

$ parted /dev/sdc
1    2048       4095     1024.0 KiB    EF02    BIOS boot partition
2    4096    1054719      513.0 MiB    8300    EFI
...

My root partition is GPT, though my BIOS from 2012 is very old and not UEFI capable.
As far as I understand I have to:

clone BIOS boot partition to a new disk
clone /boot/efi partition to a new disk
detach a folder /boot from the root partition, create a new partition on the new disk, create a mount point for it under name /boot and move the content there
edit fstab line with /boot/efi indicating new disk
run grub-install /dev/sdb
run initramfs -k -c $(uname -r)
reboot

So finally to have something like this:
$ lsblk -f
/dev/sdb
|-/dev/sdb1
|-/dev/sdb2 vfat FAT32 /boot/efi
|_/dev/sdb3 ext2 1.0   /boot

/dev/sdc
|_/dev/sdc1 ext4 1.0   /

Is that true? Or something is wrong? Please, correct me.

Having an ESP mounted at /boot/efi usually indicates efi boot, not legacy boot, so it remains unclear what is really the case here. I think you'll have to reinstall grub anyway, a step you're missing. Probably you need to edit fstab-line for boot/efi as well.

As far as I understand efi/boot is needed for gpt disks purely, while my BIOS is from 2012 and doesn't support UEFI at all.  Thanks, it is a good point to change the /boot/efi mount point.
I need more explanations whether do I need to move both /boot/efi and /boot to a new disk before encrypting the old one, and how to do it safely.

Your knowledge appears to be wrong. Boot mode is not bound to partition table type. And a Bios from 2012 should usually be efi capable.

When I run [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS I am getting BIOS, and dmesg | grep "EFI v" gives me nothing.

Then you don't need the partition mounted at /boot/efi at all. Moving bios-grub partition will render OS unbootable, grub needs to be reinstalled. I'm not sure if grub needs bios-grub partition on the same disk where grub is installed in MBR. You should install grub probably to the smaller disk's MBR, remind that bios-grub partition is only needed for GPT-disks, not for msdos-disks.

I'd assume your machine firmware (if from 2012) has uEFI support (disabled maybe), but I perform QA & still use hardware from pre-2009 that is non-uEFI (but hardware from 2009+ that is all EFI) and ESP (EFI System Partition) is not used if the machine is non-EFI capable. That is why 24.04 can install without ESP as with prior releases. I'd suggest checking your machine is pre-EFI as 2012 would imply to me it has it (just not maybe Secure-uEFI; EFI ver 2.0 was out in 2006).  If non-EFI, only the MBR matters, your machine firmware controls on which drive it's required & ESP won't be used.

@guiverc Thanks for point this. So, which scenario to pick up the better? Should I just remove /boot/efi and reinstall grub? The main idea is to make my root partition luks encrypted, and move the boot process to initramfs. As far as I understand for that I have to leave boot somewhere outside. My home server is hp n40l.

If your machine is booting in legacy (BIOS, MBR etc) mode, I'd not worry about the tinydisk space used by the ESP. Who knows, if you migrate to an uEFI box in the future it maybe useful, thus I'd just ignore it.  If not using EFI, whatever is in the ESP will be ignored, as the machine boots as setup by the firmware first (ie. firmware setting will tell which drive is to be used), then the MBR or master boot record (sector 0) is read of the disk pointed to by firmware (changing settings in firmware can impact this) which contains a pointer to the area where /boot/grub is found
